# How should you handle MongoDB-Exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to handle exceptions, which are thrown from a query (find(...).first()) to MongoDB (Driver 3.7) in Java (the database is not stored locally). However there are no possible exceptions named in the [JavaDocs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find-com.mongodb.DBObject-) and also in the MongoDB documentaton itself. Can there really occur no exceptions? I doubt that, because I think there could occur e.g. some network errors.

My queries look something like this:

```
final MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("my-collection");
final Bson bsonFilter = Filters.eq("someName", "test");
final Document result = collection.find(bsonFilter).first();
```

Comment: _"I want to handle exceptions, ..."_. You can handle exceptions the application throws, in that case. What are those application exceptions? Exceptions like network errors are not to be handled; those are system errors.  See the last paragraph in this article: [Unchecked Exceptions - The Controversy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code. It connects to a MongoDB instance locally and gets a collection named "test" from the database named "users".

```
final String connectionStr = "mongodb://localhost/";
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost/");
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("users");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
```

If you provide a wrong host name for the `connectionStr` value, like "mongodb://localhostXYZ/" (and no such host exists) the code will throw an exception, like:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: localhostXYZ}, 
caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: localhostXYZ}}],
..., ...
```

`com.mongodb.MongoSocketException` is a MongoDB Java driver exception. It is a runtime exception. It is also a sub-class of `MongoException`. From the MongoDB Java API:

> public class MongoException extends RuntimeException
>
> Top level Exception for all Exceptions, server-side or client-side, that come
>   from the driver.

The documentation also lists the following are sub-classes (all are runtime exceptions)
`MongoChangeStreamException`, `MongoClientException`, `MongoExecutionTimeoutException`, `MongoGridFSException`, `MongoIncompatibleDriverException`, `MongoInternalException`, `MongoInterruptedException`, `MongoServerException`, `MongoSocketException`.

So, all the exceptions thrown by MongoDB Java driver APIs are runtime exceptions. These are, in general, not meant to be caught and handled (but, you know how to use `try-catch`, and  a runtime exception can be caught and handled).

---

*Let us consider your code:*

```
final MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("my-collection");
final Bson bsonFilter = Filters.eq("someName", "test");
final Document result = collection.find(bsonFilter).first();
```

The first statement `database.getCollection("my-collection"),` when it runs the code is looking for a collection named "my-collection".

If you want to make sure the collection exists in the database, then verify using the `listCollectionNames​()` and check the collection name exists in the returned list. In case the collection name doesn't exist, you can throw an exception (if you want to). This exception is what you have figure:

- if you want to tell the user or the application that there was no
  such collection named "my-collection", you can show or print a
  message saying so (and then abort the program) *or* throw a runtime
  exception with an appropriate message.

So, the code might look like this:

```
if listCollectionNames​() doesn't contain "my-collection"
then 
    print something and abort the program
    -or-
    throw a runtime exception
else
     continue with program execution
```

Your code `final Document result = collection.find(bsonFilter).first();` is not correct. `collection.find` returns a `FindIterable<TDocument>` *not* a `Document`. So, the query output can be determined by further examining the `FindIterable` object; it may have documents or none. And, the `find` method doesn't throw any exceptions.

Based on if there are any documents returned or not you can show a message to the client. This is not a case you throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer prasad. I think my code: final Document result = collection.find(bsonFilter).first(); is correct, because .first() returns the first Document from the FindIterable. My problem is, that I cannot distinguish, whether  the result is equals to null, because there are simply no Documents or because there occured an error in the database. If it is the second case, I would like to retry once the request. But maybe you are right, that it's not possible to check this.

Comment: Yes, the `collection.find(bsonFilter).first();` returns a document, you are correct.

Comment: You can check for these: (i) `collection.find(bsonFilter)` returns an iterable; check if there are any documents in the iterable object, or (ii) `collection.find(bsonFilter).first();` returns a `Document`. Check if the document value is `null`. Use the _if-then-else_ logic for these. If there is an error in the database it will throw an exception, and the application will abort.  How to catch-handle such database exceptions are dependent upon your application; it is part of the application's overall design.

Comment: You can also use this code: `if (collection.find(queryFilter).iterator().tryNext() == null) { // ... }` to check for document returned.